# Reading google sheets from command line - R Linux

Tags: r, linux, command-line

Is it possible to read data from Google Sheets in R on linux from command line?

```
docs_URL <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxx"
docs <- read_sheet(docs_URL)
```

This code above starts autentication to google via web browser. This is problematic for me bacause I want to  exectue script from command line and I can not install browser.

Is it possible to authenticate to google without using web browser?

Answer (score 1):

don't know with R directly - here is a tiny open-source command line tool you could invoke from R that gives you JSON or CSV from a gsheet: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gsheet-cmd